Bullhorn API: query/NoteEntity doesn't work when one to many relation entity specified
Bullhorn API Question
NOTE to Admins:  I have asked this question on Bullhorn forum but no answer that is why asking here.
query/NoteEntity?BhRestToken={{BhRestToken}}&fields=note(id,action)&count=50&start=0&where=note.dateLastModified>1720950000000

Above call works fine but following doesn't, difference is that I have specified one to many relation entity candidates in following
query/NoteEntity?BhRestToken={{BhRestToken}}&fields=note(id,action,candidates)&count=50&start=0&where=note.dateLastModified>1720950000000

I get "An internal error has occurred" in above call.
What is the reason and how this can be corrected?
